# excuting cmd prompt through asp.net app, with more than one command line

Tags: asp.net

I'm looking to run a command prompt with a "dir" command in my web app and read the response...which I've got working but I need to to do another command first i.e. I need to use a CD to get to the proper directory.

I can get a DIR response and write it to the screen by basically using this link :

http://weblogs.asp.net/guystarbuck/archive/2008/02/06/invoking-cmd-exe-from-net.aspx

or here is the code:

```
        If Not IsPostBack Then


        Dim _info As New ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/C " & "DIR")

        ' The following commands are needed to redirect the
        ' standard output.  This means that it will be redirected
        ' to the Process.StandardOutput StreamReader.
        _info.RedirectStandardOutput = True

        ' Set UseShellExecute to false.  This tells the process to run
        ' as a child of the invoking program, instead of on its own.
        ' This allows us to intercept and redirect the standard output.
        _info.UseShellExecute = False

        ' Set CreateNoWindow to true, to supress the creation of
        ' a new window
        _info.CreateNoWindow = True

        ' Create a process, assign its ProcessStartInfo and start it
        Dim _p As New Process()
        _p.StartInfo = _info
        _p.Start()

        ' Capture the results in a string
        Dim _processResults As String = _p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()

        ' Close the process to release system resources
        _p.Close()

        ' Return the output stream to the caller
        Response.Write(_processResults)


    End If
```

The trouble it's in the wrong directory...how can I do a CD *otherdir* first?

Anyone know?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try with this command concatenation character

```
    Dim _info As New ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/C C: & CD C:\TEMP & DIR")
```

Answer (score 0):

Why so complicated? You can use this one-liner:

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\MyDir\", "*.bmp");
```

to get an array of all files (in this case, all .bmp-files) in the given directory. The extension parameter is optional.

Comment: I've only put this into the question as a simple example. i need to run an executable which is in a folder in my web directory, but I'm having all sorts of security problems. So what I was thinking was to start a command prompt process, run the executable(not do a dir) in that.

Comment: Oh, ok! What about sending the output of the command into a file, e.g. "dir /s > output.txt" and reading/parsing this file after execution?

Comment: Well it looks like Steve's answer works. I'm hosting this with a hosting company, and it looks like by website folder is in E:\Domains\s\www.mywebsite.com\user\htdocs\ and I can't seem to CD to that....so this is all probably the complete wrong approach.